# Python: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, arrays, json

This is a similar problem posted here lots of time but I am unable to get my head around it.

```
import json

str2 ="""[{'cta': [], 'ctr': 2880509, 'client_id': '229132', 'exchange': 'NSE_EQ', 'token': '3063', 'product': 'CO', 'order_type': 'M', 'duration': 'DAY', 'price': '0', 'trigger_price': '149.10', 'quantity': 1, 'disclosed_quantity': 0, 'side': 'S', 'avg_price': '148.10', 'traded_quantity': 1, 'pending_quantity': 0, 'message': '', 'exchange_order_id': '1300000006005800', 'syom_order_id': 'NA', 'order_number': '191101000336718', 'timestamp': '01/11/2019,12:19:45', 'exchange_timestamp': '01-Nov-2019 12:19:45', 'status': 'complete', 'time_in_micro': '1572590985928000', 'is_amo': False, 'order_complexity': 'CO', 'request_id': '1', 'valid_date': '--', 'tag': 'JWEB|TB1', 'comments': 'PLACE ORDER :: 229132|NSE_EQ|3063|EQ|I|0|1|S|CO|WEB|IP-172-31-4-125|1572590985897', 'fill_id': '', 'original_message': '', '_amo': False}]"""
str2 = (json.dumps(str2))
print(str2)
print(str2['client_id'])
```

Why this doesn't work? It says -

```
print(str2['client_id'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Note that str2 is output from someplace and my goal is to fetch the client_id or any other variable.

So what I am seeking is what is the possible way to parse it?

Answer (score 2):

There are *mutliple* problems here. You don't seem to be thinking this through.

You start with a string. Calling `json.dumps` on a string just gives you another string. But you couldn't have called `json.loads` on the original string either, because it is not JSON; it appears to be a string representation of a Python object.

But then, even if you had correctly parsed it, it *still* wouldn't work, because it represents a *list* of dictionaries, not a single dict.

It seems unlikely that this is actually the output from your external system. If you want further help, you will need to explain exactly how you got that string.